# Choosing signs so that sum is minimum

Tags: number-theory, analysis, elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, contest-math

Given $z_1,...,z_n\in \mathbb{C}$ how do we choose the signs $s_i\in\{-1,1\}$ such that $$S=|s_1z_1+...+s_nz_n|$$
is as small as possible? In particular I would like to know the upper and lower bounds for $S$ in terms of the $z_i$. Lower bound could be hard, e.g. how do we know if its not just zero, so upper bound is fine for starters.

It seems hard to go straight for the complex numbers so I thought about doing the reals first. My first guess was that we could say that it is less than the mean of the absolute values i.e. $S\le \frac{|z_1|+...+|z_n|}{n} $ but this is easily false e.g. $z_1=0.1, z_2=0.1, z_3=100$. Well one upper bound is $S\le \max{|z_i|}$ which we can get by using a greedy algorithm. Lastly I considered using probability and choosing the signs randomly, but we just get that the expectation is 0 and I don't know how to get more information out of that.

Comment: Probabilistic argument (this is so called Kchinchin inequality) gives second norm of $z_1,z_2,...$. Moreover, the random value is very heavily concentrated around second norm.

Comment: My guess would be that you should order the terms $z_i$ from largest to smallest then, starting with the largest, give it i.e. a positive sign, then give the next values negative signs until the sum becomes negative, then give values positive signs until the sum becomes positive, and so on.

Comment: I don't think you can do any better than $S \leq \max {|z_i|}$ without more information about the distribution of $z_i$. For instance, what if all but one of $z_i$ are zero? Then $S$ can only equal $\max {|z_i|}$

Comment: @bittahProfessional I don't think that argument eliminates the possibility of a more complicated formula which turns out to equal $\max |z_i|$ when all but one $z_i$ is zero

Comment: Not sure about $max|z_i|$ bound on account of $1, i$ values when $S$ is always $\sqrt{2}$

Comment: @Salcio Sorry that was for reals